# Notify -osd - change volume/brightness notification bar

Tags: unity, icons, notify-osd

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10, and I figured out, that it is possible to change the default icons used for notifications (basically by adding `notification-audio-volume-high.svg` etc. to your current theme (see screenshot))

[image: Brightness notify-bubble with custom icon]

While this is great, I was wondering if it is possible to change the appearance of the bar (the one that shows what the value of the brightness/volume is in the notification bubble) in order to make it more like the icon on the left.

Are there somewhere icons stored for this bar? Is there somewhere a XML file that describes its looks?

Thanks

Comment: Ohh you want the bar to be "flatter" style! I see - cool question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking into its package contents, it seems hard-coded with in the daemon. It's called [gauge](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#gauge). You need to rebuild it.

1. Get source:

   ```
   apt-get source notify-osd
   sudo apt-get build-dep notify-osd
   cd notify-osd-0.9.35+14.04.20140213/
   ```
2. Modify things you need
   `src/default.c`, sizes & size limits

   ```
   #define DEFAULT_GAUGE_SIZE           0.625f
   #define DEFAULT_GAUGE_OUTLINE_WIDTH  0.125f
   [...]
           property_gauge_size = g_param_spec_double (
                                   "gauge-size",
                                   "gauge-size",
                                   "Size/height (in em) of gauge/indicator",
                                   0.5f,
                                   1.0f,
   [...]
           property_gauge_outline_width = g_param_spec_double (
                                   "gauge-outline-width",
                                   "gauge-outline-width",
                                   "Width/thickness (in em) of gauge-outline",
                                   0.1f,
                                   0.2f,
   ```

   `src/bubble.c`, function that draw it.

   ```
   // color-, alpha-, radius-, width-, height- and gradient-values were determined
   // by very close obvervation of a SVG-mockup from the design-team
   static void
   _draw_value_indicator (cairo_t* cr,
                          gint     value,             // value to render: 0 - 100
                          gint     start_x,           // top of surrounding rect
                          gint     start_y,           // left of surrounding rect
                          gint     width,             // width of surrounding rect
                          gint     height,            // height of surrounding rect
                          gint     outline_thickness) // outline-thickness
   {
   [...]
   ```
3. Rebuild the deb package

   ```
   debuild -us -uc
   sudo dpkg --force-depends -i ../notify-osd_0.9.35+14.04.20140213-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```

   [image: modified notify-osd gauge]

**Example:**

1. Color, try this example quiet red, gradient points: RGB (0.9f,0.6f,0.6f),(0.5f,0.3f,0.3f) & (0.4f,0.2f,0.2f)

   In `bubble.c`, `_draw_value_indicator()` function below `// draw value-bar`:

   ```
           gradient = cairo_pattern_create_linear (0.0f,
                                                   start_y +
                                                   outline_thickness,
                                                   0.0f,
                                                   start_y +
                                                   outline_height -
                                                   2 * outline_thickness);
           cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient,
                                              0.0f,
                                              0.9f,
                                              0.6f,
                                              0.6f,
                                              1.0f);
           cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient,
                                              0.75f,
                                              0.5f,
                                              0.3f,
                                              0.3f,
                                              1.0f);
           cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (gradient,
                                              1.0f,
                                              0.4f,
                                              0.2f,
                                              0.2f,
                                              1.0f);

           cairo_set_source (cr, gradient);
           cairo_fill (cr);
   ```

   See [cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba ()](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-pattern-t.html#cairo-pattern-add-color-stop-rgba) in Cairo doc's.

   Comment outline drawing instructions using `/*` & `*/` so no black outline, `bar_radius = outline_height / 2;` for well rounded bar.

   ```
   // draw bar-background
   /*
   cairo_set_line_width (cr, outline_thickness);
   cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
   draw_round_rect (cr,
   [...]
   cairo_fill (cr);
   cairo_pattern_destroy (gradient);
   */
   //bar_radius = outline_radius;
   bar_radius = outline_height / 2;
   bar_width  = outline_width - 2 * outline_radius;
   //bar_height = outline_height - outline_radius;

   // draw value-bar
   ```
2. Size to `1.2f`, to look well with icon

   ```
   #define DEFAULT_GAUGE_SIZE           1.2f
   [...]
       property_gauge_size = g_param_spec_double (
                               "gauge-size",
                               "gauge-size",
                               "Size/height (in em) of gauge/indicator",
                               0.5f,
                               5.0f,
   ```
3. Here why it was cropped, it should be a bug.

   In `bubble.c`, instead `EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_icon_size (d), d) / 5.0f` it should use `EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_gauge_size (d), d)` to set the height of drawing area for gauge.

   Replace that line:

   ```
   void
   _refresh_indicator (Bubble* self)
   {
   [...]
       // create temp. scratch surface
       normal = cairo_image_surface_create (
               CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
               EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_bubble_width (d), d) -
               3 * EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_margin_size (d), d) -
               EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_icon_size (d), d)
               + 2 * BUBBLE_CONTENT_BLUR_RADIUS,
               EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_icon_size (d), d) / 5.0f
               + 2 * BUBBLE_CONTENT_BLUR_RADIUS);
   ```

   to:

   ```
   void
   _refresh_indicator (Bubble* self)
   {
   [...]
       // create temp. scratch surface
       normal = cairo_image_surface_create (
               CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
               EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_bubble_width (d), d) -
               3 * EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_margin_size (d), d) -
               EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_icon_size (d), d)
               + 2 * BUBBLE_CONTENT_BLUR_RADIUS,
               EM2PIXELS (defaults_get_gauge_size (d), d)
               + 2 * BUBBLE_CONTENT_BLUR_RADIUS);
   ```

   [image: example of custom notify-osd gauge]

Comment: Super great! Can I change the color as well somehow? Wasn't able to find it in the source code...

Comment: btw: what values did you use to get the one depicted in the answer?

Comment: @wa4557, `#define DEFAULT_ICON_SIZE 2.0f`, increased its limit from `1.0f,` to `3.0f,` in `property_gauge_size` and commented all `// draw bar-background` instructions leaving only `// draw value-bar` instructions in `_draw_value_indicator`, for color let me check

Comment: @wa4557, updated with better example.

Comment: @user.dz In 17.04, volume notification bubble( and all x-canonical-private-synchronous bubble) overlaps the panel with your patch.  Why is that?